# Calculating kg per box with loss

Tags: arithmetic

He I am not to good in math but I have a situation I need to calculate.

Sorry if this looks stupid I really doubt my self if it comes to calculating numbers.

I have the following numbers:

- gross kg: 100kg
- loss due to production: 2kg per box
- invoice kg: 8kg per box

Now I need to know how many boxes I can fill

Found the answer:

```
-------------------------------------
| raw | kg/box | los kg/box | total |
-------------------------------------
| 100 |   8kg  |    2kg     |  10kg |
-------------------------------------
```

How many boxes can I fill calculation:

`100 / 10 = 10`

`8 X 10 = 80`
chek `10 X 10 = 100` minus is trash `100 - 80 = 20`

Now I have 80kg left and I can put this in:

`80 / 8 = 20` 20 boxes of 8kg

cheksum:

### `10 X 10 = 100`

`10 X 8 = 80`

`10 X 2 = 20`

### `80 + 20 = 100`

So the final numbers are:

```
---------------------------------------------
| raw | trash |  leftover  | boxes with 8kg |
---------------------------------------------
|100kg|  20kg |    80kg    |       10       |
---------------------------------------------
```

In the end it was really easy an logic but I am dyslexic. I find it hard to calculate in my head so I have to write everything on paper. Sometime taking very long time for simple questions.

Comment: Products is not an appropriate tag as it is meant for products in the mathematical sense.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: Well I find it hard to explain but I try: I have X kg raw product and I need to fill boxes with X kg. But in the work proces X kg per box is lost. I have 100kg raw product and in have boxes for 8kg I lose 2 kg product per box to fill. So I need to calculate how many boxes I can fill whit 8 kg from what is leftover. Due to my calculations that is 75 kg. Is the calculation right. #Michael Corleone I don't know where to put this. Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very hard, but I'm not english, so maybe I misunderstood gross, invoice,..
I don't understand how you checked your solution either ^^

### What you already know

**Raw materials:** 100kg
**Box contents:** 8kg
**Lost per box:** 2kg

### Easy way

$\frac{raw}{\frac{raw}{box}} = \frac{100kg}{8kg+2kg} = 10$ boxes

### Percentage solution

$\eta = \frac{8kg}{8kg+2kg} =  0.8 = 80\%$

$\eta \cdot 100kg = 80kg$

$n = \frac{80kg}{8\frac{kg}{box}} = 10$ boxes

Comment: That is it, thank you very much. And I am dutch we have brutto and netto. Not sure how to put it in English. And an extra compliment for the Percentage solution. Very handy so great mate!!

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to solve this is to say that in order to fill *one* box, you need 10 kg of produce, of which 8 kg will go into the box and 2 kg onto the floor. With 100 kg in all, you can fill 100/10 = 10 boxes.

The problem with your calculation is that you are trying to determine the total waste *before* you know the total number of boxes. Your first number 12.5 is the number of boxes you would be able to fill if there were no waste. Your second number 25 (kg) is the total waste if you fill 12.5 boxes. In reality, you will not be able to fill 12.5 boxes because of the waste, so the total waste will be *less* than 25 kg. Hence you will not get the right answer when you use the number 25 kg in your calculations.